# Calculate overlaps of time ranges with time range

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I try to calculate the amount (in minutes) of overlaps between a given time range and an array of time ranges.

First I order the ranges by start time, and filter them, if they not overlap with the range.

```js
const range = ["2019-11-06 08:00", "2019-11-06 17:00"]; // 9h
const ranges = [
  ["2019-11-06 00:00", "2019-11-06 10:00"],
  ["2019-11-06 22:00", "2019-11-06 24:00"],
  ["2019-11-06 09:00", "2019-11-06 12:00"]
]

function calculateOvelappings(range, ranges) {
  const start = moment(range[0])
  const end = moment(range[1])
  let overlaps = 0
  // order ranges by start time
  ranges = ranges.sort((a, b) => moment(a[0]).unix() - moment(b[0]).unix())
  for(let i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    const rangeStart = moment(ranges[i][0])
    const rangeEnd = moment(ranges[i][1])
    if (rangeEnd.isBefore(start) || rangeStart.isAfter(end)) {
      continue;
    }
    
  }
  return overlaps
}


console.log(calculateOvelappings(range, ranges))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/2.14.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT**

The right answer for overlaps would be 4 hours. The input range starts at 08:00 in intersects with range 1 (from the array) till 10:00 (2 hours). Range 2 is irrelevant. Range 3 overlaps with the input range from 09:00 to 12:00, but from 09:00 to 10:00 is already calculated from range 1. Therefor 2 + (3 - 1) = 4 hours.

Is there an elegant algorithm, to calculate this?
Any help would be appreciated, a pseudo code, or even a theoretical answare.

Here is a JsBin: https://jsbin.com/noyuhekura/1/edit?js,console

Comment: Well, you never update `overlaps`, so it will always be 0. What's the question?

Comment: I think `Array.reduce` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is what you want. I don't believe sorting the ranges gives you a benefit in terms of performance. I would do something like `ranges.reduce((totalOverlapMinutes, currentRange) => totalOverlapMinutes + computeOverlapBetween(range, currentRange))`

Comment: @kraf please read me edit. The problem with your approach, it  calculates two times if the ranges overlap with each other.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const range = ["2019-11-06 08:00", "2019-11-06 17:00"]; // 9h
const ranges = [
  ["2019-11-06 00:00", "2019-11-06 10:00"],
  ["2019-11-06 22:00", "2019-11-06 24:00"],
  ["2019-11-06 09:00", "2019-11-06 12:00"]
]

function calculateOvelappings(range, ranges) {
  const start = moment(range[0])
  const end = moment(range[1])
  let overlaps = 0
  // order ranges by start time
  ranges = ranges.sort((a, b) => moment(a[0]).unix() - moment(b[0]).unix())
  for(let i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    const rangeStart = moment(ranges[i][0])
    const rangeEnd = moment(ranges[i][1])
    if (rangeEnd.isBefore(start) || rangeStart.isAfter(end)) {
      continue;
    }
    overlaps += rangeEnd - rangeStart // Updated
  }
  return overlaps
}


console.log(calculateOvelappings(range, ranges))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```